# Counting maximal subgroups in a finite $p$-group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group. I want to show that if the number of maximal subgroups is strictly less than $p+1$ then $G$ is cyclic. This may not be true, but if the number of maximal subgroups is always $\equiv 1 $ modulo $p$, then our hypothesis forces there to be exactly one maximal subgroup. The result of course follows from this. Is this the right approach?

Comment: $G$ acts on these maximal subgroups via conjugation, and if there's less than $p+1$, you can then embed $G$/$H$ in $S_p$, where $H$ fixes all maximal subgroups.  $H$ is the center, and the $p$-subgroups of $S_p$ are order $p$.

Comment: But yes, your approach works as well.

Answer (score 1):

You said, *...if the number of maximal subgroups is always $\equiv 1\pmod p$ ...*

Here, you may ignore *if*, since this fact is always true in $p$-groups.

---

Thus, if the number of maximal subgroups is less than $p+1$, it must be $1$ only, and it is an easy exercise to show that the group must be cyclic (consider an element outside unique maximal subgroup, and look at the subgroup generated by it, how will we proceed then? Exercise!)

Comment: Could you please prove this fact that the number of maximal subgroups is always $\equiv 1\pmod{p}$?
My sketch of proof - We can prove that the commutator of the $p-$group is contained inside every maximal subgroup. Using this it only reduces to prove for abelian groups. How to do the rest?

Comment: @Grobber: The intersection of all the maximal subgroups is the Frattini subgroup $\Phi(G)$.  The quotient $G/\Phi(G)$ is an elementary abelian group, so you're just counting codimension-one vector spaces (or, using duality, linear subspaces, of which there are $\dfrac{p^k-1}{p-1}$ for some $k$).  That fraction is congruent to $1\pmod{p}$.